# ggdag plot backdoor paths only

Tags: directed-acyclic-graphs, ggdag, dagitty

How can I use ggdag to plot backdoor paths only?

For instance, given the following code:

```
library(ggdag)

tidy_ggdag <- dagify(
    y ~ t + x1,
    t ~ x1,
    exposure = "t",
    outcome = "y"
) %>% tidy_dagitty()

ggdag_paths(tidy_ggdag) + theme_dag()
```

It plots all open paths, not only backdoor ones:

[image]